# Google Anlaytics Api reporting - filter homepage

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to filter views by page. In particular i'm only interested in views on homepage of a website. I know that homepage in our website are just identified "/"

This is the body

```
body={
    'reportRequests': [
        {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'dateRanges': [
                {'startDate': queryDate_begin.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 'endDate': queryDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}],
            'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}
                        ],
            'dimensions': [
                           {'name': 'ga:date'},
                           {'name': 'ga:dimension11'},
                           {'name': 'ga:pagePath'}
                           ],

            'dimension_filter_clauses': [
                {
                    'operator': 'EXACT',
                    'filters': [
                        {
                            'dimensionName': 'ga:pagePath',
                            'not': False,
                            'expressions': [
                                "/"
                            ],
                            'caseSensitive': False
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ],

            # Taken from `nextPageToken` of a previous response.
            'pageToken': offset,
            'pageSize': 10000

        }
    ]}).execute()
```

I'm using python api client with a batchrequest.

I keep getting a response error:

```
b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Invalid value at \'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].operator\' (TYPE_ENUM), \\"EXACT\\"",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Invalid value at \'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].operator\' (TYPE_ENUM), \\"EXACT\\"",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "badRequest"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n'
```

I know that the error is linked to the `dimension_filter_clauses` and probably to the "/" filters.

Anyone knows how to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your set dimension_filter_clauses.operator to "EXACT". That is not a valid value for this field.

dimension_filter_clauses.operator can be on of ("OR", "AND") see the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#FilterLogicalOperator

Since you only have one filter, it shouldn't matter which one you pick. You can leave it out of your request and it will default to OR. 
I hope that helps.